# How to hook first hashtaged word in text

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP *$var* result named *'$caption'* result. That result sometimes have #hashtag words like Instagram or Twitter for example;

> The Caipirinha is similar to a mojito, except there’s no mint … and there are a lot more limes. **#Rio** #Olympics #RiodeJaneiro #Caipirinha

I just want hook in text first hastagged word **(bold)**.

In ***PHP*** how i can do (hook) first hastagged words in text($var result)?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Usng `regexp`. Using `strpos` and `substr`.

Comment: What do you mean by "hook"?

Comment: You want to make the first `#word` bold...or?

Comment: @Chris I mean by hook "grep"

Comment: @chris85 No, just want to grep first #hastaged word with PHP echo. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_match` with a regex to match the first `#word`. Something like:

```
$string = 'The Caipirinha is similar to a mojito, except there’s no mint … and there are a lot more limes. #Rio #Olympics #RiodeJaneiro #Caipirinha';
preg_match('/#\S+/', $string, $firsthashedword);
echo $firsthashedword[0];
```

Should do it. `\S` is any non-whitespace character. The `+` is a quantifier meaning there must be at least one non-whitespace character after the `#`. Once it encounters a whitespace the match stops.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/619122
Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mE8lB6/1

Comment: Thank you so much @chris85 you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $result = "This is a sample result #cool #muchwow";
    $split = explode("#", $result);    
    $returnStr = '<b>#'.$split[1].'</b>';
    echo str_replace('#'.$split[1], $returnStr, $result);
?>
```

Output:

```
This is a sample result <b>#cool</b> #muchwow
```

Explode will set `$split` to an array containing the words in between the hashtags.

So in your example the `$split` variable would equal ['Rio','Olympics'...etc]. Then I find the first occurrence of the '#' which would be equal to $split[1].

After I have that I perform a simple `str_replace()` to look for the first hashtag adding in html bold tags.

Check it out here: https://eval.in/619127

Comment: oh and the echo is just to see the output, if you wanted you could set it back to the original result variable